# Passing each column of a table to a UDF

Tags: javascript, python, sql, google-bigquery, udf

I need to write a script in Python using which I run a query on all the columns of the table uploaded on bigquery.
I understand that I can select individual columns by their names and process them like :
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table_name
and then write a UDF in javascript to do my processing.

But, my requirement is to obtain all the column names of the schema(suppose as a list) and then one by one pass the elements of the list in the select statement like suppose the list of column names is l = [col1,col2,col3...]
I want to do something like:

```
for i in range(0,len(l):
    SELECT DISTINCT l[i] from table_name
```

so that I do not need to hard code the column names of the schema in my code.
How can I do this bigquery using standard sql?
or is it not possible and I need to pass my entire dataset into javascript UDF and then do all my processing there?

Comment: Are you trying to apply the UDF to each column separately? Or does the UDF take some subset of the columns? I don't quite understand the shape of the query that you are trying to produce.

Comment: I need to pass each column to the UDF one at a time

Answer (score 0):

There is no way currently to apply a user-defined function to each column in a table separately without enumerating all of them. One idea is to do row-based processing instead, though that still requires listing the column names and types as part of the function definition. For example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION ProcessRow(t STRUCT<x FLOAT64, y STRING, z BOOL>)
RETURNS STRUCT<x FLOAT64, y STRING, z BOOL> LANGUAGE js AS """
  function ProcessColumn(x) {
    // (Some processing here)
    return x;
  }

  var new_t = new Object();
  for (var property in t) {
    if (t.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      new_t[property] = ProcessColumn(t[property]);
    }
  }
  return new_t;
""";

WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x, 'foo' AS y, true AS z
)
SELECT ProcessRow(t).*
FROM YourTable t;
```

This would be simpler if BigQuery supported templated functions, which you can [star on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905991) to register your interest.